# How to getCurrentPageNumber() in Itext 7

Tags: java, pdf, itext, pdf-generation, itext7

In Itext 5, PdfWriter used to have a method called **getCurrentPageNumber()**.
Itext 7 does not have it anymore.

How can I get the current page number since the entire pdf is going to use the same Document instance ( **PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(writer)**)from start to end?

Use case: An apllication written using itext5 needs to be rewritten using itext7.
Our app generates PDF files for our customer's monthly bills.

Structure of the pdf:

1. Create document:

   ```
    PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(new FileOutputStream(filename));
    PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(writer);
    Document document = new Document(pdfDocument, PageSize.A4);
    document.setMargins(235, 35, 0, 38);
    buildBody(pdfData, document, writer);
   ```
2. For every page I use an IEventHandler for the Start and another one for the End of the pages to add some data at the Header and Footer.

   ```
    pdfDocument.addEventHandler(PdfDocumentEvent.START_PAGE, new  
    StartPageHandler<>(pdfData, document, this));
    pdfDocument.addEventHandler(PdfDocumentEvent.END_PAGE, new  
    EndPageHandler<>(pdfData, document, this));
   ```

3.Each IEventHandler instance has this format(except the rectangle values):

```
Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(51, 50, 500, 60); (This is for the END_PAGE)
Rectangle[] columns = new Rectangle[] {rectangle};
document.setRenderer(new ColumnDocumentRenderer(document, columns));
document.add(lineSeparatorHeader);
document.add(paragraphInfo); // information used in the Header/Footer
```

4. The **buildBody(pdfData, document, writer)** method (from step 1) was using the **writer.getCurrentPageNumber()** method in order to check if the content we wanted to add has exceeded the space on the page and has passed on another page. If it passed on another page, I would have to add some extra information (somehow as a title in the body of the page) before the rest of the content is added. (It used to work with itext5)

Comment: In iText 7 you don't necessarily have a single current page number anymore as you don't necessarily have a single `Document` (or similar) object working on your PDF anymore. Thus, please explain the context some more.

Comment: I have updated the description of the problem. Any documentation links that explain how  paging  and  layouts work  in itext7 are highly appreciated.

Comment: Do I understand your item 4 correctly that the `buildBody` method used to call `getCurrentPageNumber` itself? I.e. not some event listener as described in item 2 and 3 but `buildBody` itself? In that case I assume the presence of the event listeners is irrelevant, isn't it? I'll write an answer under that assumption.

Comment: Yes. buildBody() used to call getCurrentPageNumber() itself. The presence of the listener is not irelevant since it is used for the generation of the HEADER and of the FOOTER on every new page. The buildBody() method does not have anything to do with the FOOTER and the HEADER. It only must generate content for inbetween HEADER and FOOTER

Comment: *"The presence of the listener is not irelevant"* - then how does it influence the `getCurrentPageNumber()` call in `buildBody()`?

Comment: When you said: "In that case I assume the presence of the event listeners is irrelevant, isn't it? ", it makes me think of irrelevant in the entire context. The presence of the IEventListener is irelevant for the buildBody() method, BUT it is relevant for the HEADER and the FOOTER of every page. I think this is just a communication missunderstanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that the code you want to port apparently used the iText 5 `PdfDocument`/`PdfWriter` pattern, the *current page number* in that code always was the *currently last page number*, i.e. the *current number of pages* in the document being created.

In iText 7 these numbers are not automatically the same; if you port the code keeping the general architecture, though, those numbers most likely will remain the same in your iText 7 code, too.

In iText 7 you can get the *current number of pages* from the `PdfDocument` in question:

```
PdfDocument pdfDocument = ...;
...
int currentNamberOfPages = pdfDocument.getNumberOfPages();
```

Currently your `buildBody` method signature does not include the `PdfDocument` (which made sense in iText 5). For iText 7 you should consider changing the signature to include the `PdfDocument`. Most likely, though, you won't need the `PdfWriter` anymore which you then can exclude.

If you need to keep that method signature for some obscure reason, you can retrieve the `PdfDocument` from the `Document` using the `getPdfDocument` method.

Comment: You are right. Since I am using the same Document instance from start to end, pdfDocument.getNumberOfPages() returns the page I am currently working on. Thank you!